# WebDAV request-response examples? Especially PROPFIND

Tags: webdav

I'm currently implementing a WebDAV server and am totally stuck at the PROPFIND method handling. Are there any resources out there with actual examples? I have a hard time following the specification, which is imo very vague. Here's e.g. a request "Litmus" sends my server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:propfind xmlns:a="DAV:" xmlns="DAV:">
    <b:prop xmlns:b="DAV:">
        <b:getcontentlength/>
        <b:getlastmodified/>
        <b:displayname/>
        <b:resourcetype/>
        <c:foo xmlns:c="http://example.com/neon/litmus/" xmlns="http://example.com/neon/litmus/"/>
        <bar/>
    </b:prop>
</a:propfind>
```

Apparently, my response to that is not okay, since Litmus says "4. propfind_d0........... FAIL (No responses returned)":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DAV:multistatus
    xmlns:DAV="DAV:">
    <DAV:response>
        <DAV:href>/test/litmus/</DAV:href>
        <DAV:propstat>
            <DAV:prop>
                <DAV:getlastmodified>Fri, 30 Sep 2016 23:28:31 +0000</DAV:getlastmodified>
                <DAV:displayname>litmus</DAV:displayname>
                <DAV:resourcetype>
                    <DAV:collection></DAV:collection>
                </DAV:resourcetype>
            </DAV:prop>
            <DAV:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</DAV:status>
        </DAV:propstat>
        <DAV:propstat>
            <DAV:prop>
                <DAV:getcontentlength></DAV:getcontentlength>
                <a:foo
                    xmlns:a="http://example.com/neon/litmus/">
                </a:foo>
                <a:bar></a:bar>
            </DAV:prop>
            <DAV:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</DAV:status>
        </DAV:propstat>
    </DAV:response>
</DAV:multistatus>
```

What would be a correct response, and how can I actually find out?

Comment: One problem is that you were asked for the properties "foo" in namespace "http://example.com/neon/litmus/" and "bar" in the empty namespace, but returned "not found" results for "foo" and "bar" in the "DAV:" namespace.

Comment: I corrected that - see edit - but the problem still persists...

Comment: The response above right now doesn't  parse; the element "<a:bar>" doesn't have a namespace declaration.